# Proving $\int_a^b f = - \int_b^a f$ from the reflection property of the integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

My confusion is book specific (Calculus by Apostol). On page 100, the author claims $\int_{-\pi/2}^0 cos(x) dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} cos(-x) dx$ follows from the reflection property of the integral, which is given in the textbook as $\int_a^b f(x) dx = 1/k \int_{ka}^{kb} f(x/k) dx$ and $k=-1$. I don't follow. How exactly is the property being used here? I understand cosine is symmetric around the y-axis, but I just don't see the logic as given by the author.

I just don't see how you can use the reflection property to prove this.

Comment: It may help clear up a bit of confusion to note that $\cos(x) = \cos(-x)$ follows from cosine being an even function, not from the reflection property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity follows from *two* facts: (1) The so-called reflection identity $\int_a^b f(x) f dx = \frac{1}{k} \int_{ka}^{kb} f(x/k) dx$ and (2) the identity $\int_a^b f(x)dx = -\int_b^a f(x) dx$.

Indeed, let $k=-1$ and use (1) to get
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^0 \cos(x) dx = \frac{1}{-1} \int_{\pi/2}^0 \cos(x/(-1)) dx=-\int_{\pi/2}^0 \cos(-x) dx.$$

Next, use (2) to conclude that 
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^0 \cos(x) dx = -\int_{\pi/2}^0 \cos(-x) dx.  dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(-x) dx.$$

Why does property (2) hold? It's just by definition. When the integral is define in a manner relating to area, it makes sense to have $a<b$. It turns out it is convenient to define the integral from $b$ to $a$ as the negative of this area.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx=-\int_{b}^{a}\,dx$$
Consider $[a,b]$ to be the integration bound. If $a<b$ then $\Delta x=b-a$ is positive so it will not affect the sign of the integral but if the $b<a$ then the $\Delta x$ will be negative and regardless of the sign of the integrand function in the integration interval it will affect the integral sign, so when we reverse the bounds for the sake of equality we add the negative sign, called reflection properties.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, Apostol defines $\int_a^b f$ in terms of step functions above and below $f$ which is essentially equivalent to the definition using Darboux sums.

So when $a > b$, $\int_a^b f$ doesn't actually make sense according to the definition. We take it to be $-\int_b^a f$ because (a) it makes all the formulas (especially substitution) work, and (b) when one introduces the generalized Stokes' theorem one sees the connection: the latter integral is still integrating over $[a,b]$, but where it has been given the opposite orientation.